# SOLVED: DiscordJS v14: Expected undefined or null, Expected a bigint primitive, Expected a number primitive, Expected a string primitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a ban command and this error keeps popping up:

```
D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:47
    throw this.error;
    ^

CombinedError: Received one or more errors
    at UnionValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1058:23)
    at UnionValidator.parse (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)
    at validateDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:877:36)
    at MixedClass.setDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1345:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projs\js\MASST\commands\ban.js:15:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {
  errors: [
    ValidationError: Expected undefined or null
        at NullishValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:718:79)
        at NullishValidator.run (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:99:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1053:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)
        at validateDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:877:36)
        at MixedClass.setDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1345:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projs\js\MASST\commands\ban.js:15:4)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
      validator: 's.nullish',
      given: [ 2048n, 65536n, 4n ]
    },
    ValidationError: Expected a bigint primitive
        at BigIntValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:520:70)
        at BigIntValidator.run (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:99:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1053:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)
        at validateDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:877:36)
        at MixedClass.setDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1345:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projs\js\MASST\commands\ban.js:15:4)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
      validator: 's.bigint',
      given: [ 2048n, 65536n, 4n ]
    },
    ValidationError: Expected a number primitive
        at NumberValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:866:70)
        at NumberValidator.run (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:99:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1053:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)
        at validateDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:877:36)
        at MixedClass.setDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1345:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projs\js\MASST\commands\ban.js:15:4)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
      validator: 's.number',
      given: [ 2048n, 65536n, 4n ]
    },
    ValidationError: Expected a string primitive
        at StringValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1672:70)
        at StringValidator.run (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:99:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1053:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:88)
        at validateDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:877:36)
        at MixedClass.setDefaultMemberPermissions (D:\projs\js\MASST\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1345:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projs\js\MASST\commands\ban.js:15:4)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
      validator: 's.string',
      given: [ 2048n, 65536n, 4n ]
    }
  ]
}
```

ban.js:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

const botPerms = [
    PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages,
    PermissionFlagsBits.ReadMessageHistory,
    PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers,
];

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        // Command name. Example: /choices
        .setName('ban')
        // Command's description. Shows up in commands menu once / is typed.
        .setDescription('Bans specified user')
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(botPerms)
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('User to ban.')
                .setRequired(true),
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('reason')
                .setDescription('Why was the user banned?')
                .setRequired(true),
        ),

    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has(botPerms)) {
            const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');
            const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason');

            if (user.bannable === true) {
                interaction.guild.members.ban(user);
                interaction.reply('Banned!');

                try {
                    user.send(`You have been banned from ${interaction.guild.name}!\nReason::${reason}`);
                }

                catch (error) {
                    interaction.followUp('Failed to DM banned user.');
                }
            }
        }
    },
};
```

deploy-commands.js:

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    }
    catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

What's wrong?
I as well couldn't find anything about it on the internet. The logs don't really help, but I for sure know the error is caused by ban.js. No idea how though.

`node deploy-commands.js` and `node init.js` — both gave out same error. I am really clueless about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are not handling your error. You'll get a nicely formatted error if you catch it... so catch it!

Moving on to the problem, `.setDefaultMemberPermissions(botPerms)` is the issue. Let's explain the logs: it says it expected `undefined` or `null`, a `bigint`, a `number` or a `string`. However, you gave `[2048n, 65536n, 4n]`. An array, of course, is none of these. This is why you get the error.

You cannot give a list of permissions here. You should do `const botPerms = PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages | PermissionFlagsBits.ReadMessageHistory | PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers` instead. The `|` is a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) which joins the permissions together, setting the default member permissions to all of these.

Here is the relevant documentation link: https://discordjs.dev/docs/packages/builders/main/SlashCommandBuilder:Class#setDefaultMemberPermissions